# Get subsite subsites titles

Tags: powershell

```
    param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[String]$StartWeb,
[Boolean]$IncludeStartWeb = $false
)

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Get all subsites for the provided site
$subsites = ((Get-SPWeb $StartWeb).Site).allwebs | ?{$_.url -like "$StartWeb*"}

foreach($subsite in $subsites)
{

Write-Host $subsite.Url


}
```

This will get the whole url like this `http://sp2013/sub1/sub2` like this,

But i only want to get the url `/sub1/sub2`

When typing `$subsite.Name` it will only get `/sub1` and not `/sub2`?
How should I get `/sub2` also?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$subsite.ServerRelativeUrl`